# creation of jar failing

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a jar using the following command on a RHEL box

```
jar -cf first MANIFEST.TXT HelloWorld.class
```

the contents of MANIFEST.TXT is
Main-Class: HelloWorld

This is failing with the following error 
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
first

I understand i need to create the manifest file which has Main-Class manifest even with this I cannot execute
java -jar first without an error

Thanks 
Bhavya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the example from `jar -help`:

```
jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

You must specify `m` so jar knows there is a manifest file and you should not omit the `.jar` from `first`. This should work:

```
jar cfm first.jar MANIFEST.TXT HelloWorld.class
```